# DotNetZip ZipInputStream issue

Tags: c#, aes, dotnetzip, bzip2, zipinputstream

I use DotNetZip 1.9.3 library and have faced a problem using BZip2 and AES256 both for 1 entry within 1 archive. ZipOutputStream works fine, but ZipInputStream gets wrong BZip2 header. If I use commom deflate algorithm, everything is fine.

I create ZipOutputStream (from file stream):

```
protected override Stream OnCreateStream(string path)
{
    var encryptedStream = new ZipOutputStream(base.OnCreateStream(path))
    {
        Password = this.Password,
        Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256,
   //     CompressionMethod = CompressionMethod.BZip2,
    };
    var entry = encryptedStream.PutNextEntry("_");
    return encryptedStream;
}
```

And I always dispose ZipOutputStream when the job is done.

Stream to read zip archive:

```
protected override Stream OnCreateStream(string path)
{
    ZipInputStream stream = new ZipInputStream(base.OnCreateStream(path))
    {
        Password = this.Password
    };
    var entry = stream.GetNextEntry();
    return stream;
}
```

If I uncomment compression method and tries to read ZipInputStream I get exception:

```
Not a valid BZip2 stream. byte 1, expected '90', got '107'
   в Ionic.BZip2.BZip2InputStream.CheckMagicChar(Char expected, Int32 position)
   в Ionic.BZip2.BZip2InputStream.init()
   в Ionic.BZip2.BZip2InputStream..ctor(Stream input, Boolean leaveOpen)
   в Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.GetExtractDecompressor(Stream input2)
   в Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.InternalOpenReader(String password)
   в Ionic.Zip.ZipInputStream.SetupStream()
   в Ionic.Zip.ZipInputStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   в System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer(Char[] userBuffer, Int32 userOffset, Int32 desiredChars, Boolean& readToUserBuffer)
   в System.IO.StreamReader.Read(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's quite old topic, but it may be still useful for someone googling for solution.

I've noticed that order of invoking compression's property setters is important. With

```
zip.CompressionMethod = CompressionMethod.BZip2;
zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;
```

set before `AddEntry` makes ZIP file unreadable by DotNetZip. Right place of setting `CompressionMethod` and `CompressionLevel` is just before saving:

```
using (var zip = new ZipFile(zipPath, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    // set zip properties except compression ones
    zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256;
    zip.Password = "pass";

    // add entries
    zip.AddEntry("whatever", stream);

    // set compression just before Save()
    zip.CompressionMethod = CompressionMethod.BZip2;
    zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;

    zip.Save();
}
```

Comment: This was the exakt problem I had. Funny thing is that with the compression level and compression method just before the save my files are 10-20% bigger .. but they are also readable..

Comment: I had the same problem, but I 've noticed that the ZIP was readable by achievers other than DotNetZip. Also, since this fix increases the size of the archive, it suggests to me that the compression method is not applied with this fix. Most likely this should be fixed in the library's code.

Answer (score 0):

This probably hints to the problem:

> Like gzip, bzip2 is only a data compressor. It is not an archiver like tar or ZIP; the program itself has no facilities for multiple files, encryption or archive-splitting, but, in the UNIX tradition, relies instead on separate external utilities such as tar and GnuPG for these tasks.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip2#Compression_efficiency)